# How to allocate/genrate new ip address in ec2 instance in same subnet range?

Tags: networking, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, subnet

I know i can get new IP address by going to Elastic IPs --> Allocate new address
but by doing this i always get IPs in different subnet range.

I want to IPs with same subnet.

Comment: The answer is effectively "no," but it seems like "Why do you need this?" is a reasonable question, to verify that you aren't trying to solve the wrong problem.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to do this with EIPs.  They are allocated from a public pool using an algorithm that is opaque.

If you already have -- or have the means to acquire -- a block of *your own* public IP addresses, then some regions support [bring your own IP](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-byoip.html) which allows you to have AWS advertise your addresses so that you can allocate them from your own public address pool, which would by definition be in a contiguous block.  This is not likely to be cost-effective, if it's even possible, due to the scarcity of IPv4 addresses.